# How can I add .aspx inside HyperLink in DataList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have created an DataList with Hyperlinks inside of it. But... It's redirecting me to for example: /itemName, but i want to redirect it to /itemName.aspx. When i add to the Eval .aspx its putting an error.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="120px">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("itemName") %>' Text='<%# Eval("nazwa") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide your code and markup?

Comment: Are you using friendly url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by editing Eval like this:

```
Eval("itemName", "~/{0}.aspx")
```